# Why $U\subseteq V ,\text{ U is a subspace of V }\wedge \dim U = \dim V \iff U=V$ only holds if the dimension is finite?

Tags: linear-algebra

By Definition of $\dim$ the Statement on the left side, i.e $\dim U = \dim V $, would mean there exists a bijective map between a base of $U$ and a base of $V$.

We have also said that if $B,\tilde{B}$ are bases of $V$ then there exists a bijective map between $B,\tilde{B}$.

If I am not wrong the opposite implication is not true, i.e if we have a bijective map between a base of $V$ and a other set this other set must also be a base of $V$ because then the Statement in the Question would be also Right for the infinite case.

My Question is if the opposite implication is true or not and if it is true why does the Statement in the Question does not hold for the infinite case.
And if it is not true what would be a counterexample?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the vector space $V$ of all infinite sequences of real numbers that are eventually zero (i.e., have only finitely many nonzero terms). It has a basis 
$$
e_1 = 1,0,0,0, \ldots\\
e_2 = 0,1,0,0, \ldots\\
\ldots
$$
Now let $U$ be the subset spanned by $e_2, e_4, e_6, \ldots$. There's a bijection between the basis of $V$ and the basis of $U$, given by sending $e_i$ to $e_{2i}$. But evidently $U \ne V$.

Brief summary: infinities can be weird.